# Add Python 3.7 to Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to add another version to my PYcharm editor (currently running python 3.8) and for some reason i can't do that, although i think i'm not doing anything wrong.
Here's my steps.

```
 Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Settings -> Add -> System Interpreter -> Base Interpreter -> ...
```

another variation that i tried without success:

```
Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Settings -> Add -> Virtualenv Environment -> Base Interpreter -> ...
```

Here's the path to python 3.7 file:

```
 C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7\Python 3.7 (32-bit).lnk
```

I have renamed it to the following but still didn't work

```
C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7\Python.exe
```

For reference here's my python 8 path

```
C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
```

different location, but it shouldn't matter.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have added is not the exe, it's just the shortcut (`.lnk`) file to the exe. So even though you renamed it, that will not work! What you can do is you can right-click and select `Open file location` and get the real exe pathname and add it to Pycharm.

Steps with pictures:

1. Get the real Python exe path
   [image]
   Right-click on the `Python 3.7` shortcut
   [image]
   After that, it will show you the real exe path. For example, my Python 3.7 is in VS dir.
   [image]
2. After that you can do like what you did:

   Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Settings -> Add -> System Interpreter -> Base Interpreter -> ...
   (Sorry but I can't take screenshots for this step. Do what you did and it should be ok.)